# Sed to match special characters and add special characters

Tags: regex, sed

I trying to do 3 operations on a file using sed.

1. remove {master} if its above specific string "string@string>string|string"
2. remove date "Oct 14 22:55:58" if its below specific string "string@string>string|string"
3. add a string " after matching ""

"test@test-re0> show version | display xml" is just an example and it can vary and also can have spaces or no spaces after special characters '>', '|'. But format is same i.e. string@string>string|string

Example:

```
{master}
test@test-re0> show version | display xml
Oct 14 22:55:58 
<rpc-reply>
</rpc-reply>

test@test-re0> show hardware|display xml
Jan 04 01:55:58 
<rpc-reply>
</rpc-reply>
```

Expected result

```
test@test-re0> show version | display xml
<rpc-reply">
</rpc-reply>
<ENDSTRING>

test@test-re0> show hardware|display xml
<rpc-reply>
</rpc-reply>
<ENDSTRING>
```

```
1.sed "/^{master}$/d" input.txt - This matches and deletes {master}
2.[a-zA-Z]{3}\s*\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d - regex matches date but doesn't work in sed
3.sed "/^</rpc-reply>/a <ENDSTRING>" input.txt - Doesnot work
```

I want to combine all 3 operations into single command and save it to separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `sed` script to do this all in a single `sed` command:

```bash
cat cmd.sed

/^\{master}/ {
   N
   s/.+\n([^@]+@[^|]+\|.)/\1/
}
/^[^@]+@[^|]+\|./ {
   N
   s/(.+)\n[A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}/\1/
}
/^<\/rpc-reply>/a \
<ENDSTRING>
```

Use it as:

```bash
sed -E -f cmd.sed file

test@test-re0> show version | display xml22:55:58
<rpc-reply>
</rpc-reply>
<ENDSTRING>

test@test-re0> show hardware|display xml01:55:58
<rpc-reply>
</rpc-reply>
<ENDSTRING>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N
        s/^\{master\}\n(\S+@\S+>\s+\S[^\n]*\|[^\n]*)/\1/;ta
        s/^(\S+@\S+>\s+\S[^\n]*\|[^\n]*)\n... .. ..:..:..[^\n]*/\1/;ta
        /\n<\/rpc-reply>$/{P;s/.*\n(.*)/\1\n<ENDSTRING>/};P;D' file
```

Open up a two line window throughout the file by appending the next line.

If the first line of the window is `{master}`, delete that line and append the next line i.e. repeat from the start.

If the second line of the window contains a date, delete that line and append the next line i.e. repeat from the start.

If the second line of the window contains `</rpc-reply>`, print the first line of the window, delete the first line of the window and append the required string.

Print/delete the first line of the window and repeat.

---

If you prefer it as a one-liner:

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/^\{master\}\n(\S+@\S+>\s+\S[^\n]*\|[^\n]*)/\1/;ta;s/^(\S+@\S+>\s+\S[^\n]*\|[^\n]*)\n... .. ..:..:..[^\n]*/\1/;ta;/\n<\/rpc-reply>$/{P;s/.*\n(.*)/\1\n<ENDSTRING>/};P;D' file
```

Comment: Thanks Potong. I need to accept anubhava answer as its single command

Comment: @Knightfox it is a single sed set of commands, I just split it over 4 lines so that it was more readable. If you prefer, you can replace every newline (between single quotes) with `;`.

Comment: Apologies. The single command works. Thanks for your help.